# Can't compile my Xamarin app because it uses System.Web namespace

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I have a Xamarin app I'm trying to compile in VS2019, but I get this error:

> Can not resolve reference: `System.Web`, referenced by `ApiPrototypeClientMobile` > `XXX.Core`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Web`, or remove the reference to `ApiPrototypeClientMobile`.

where XXX is the name of my application.

I tried adding a reference to System.Net (and System.Web.Services for good measure) to my ApiPrototypeClientMobile.Android project; I would add them to ApiPrototypeClientMobile, but there is no way to do so with that project as it is a .NET Standard class library. I also tried adding System.Net.Http as a NuGet package to the ApiPrototypeClientMobile project, but that didn't help either; there is no System.Web to add. How can I get rid of this error so I can build my project? Thanks! :)

Comment: System.Web.HttpUtility exists in NetStd2.0+, Xamarin.iOS|Android, etc... but the rest of the System.Web exists in the .Net full frameworks as it is designed for (ASP) server usage.

Comment: So I can't use System.Web in a .NET Standard project, then? I guess what I'd have to do is factor out the parts of the XXX.Core project that I'm using into a separate project that does not use System.Web?

Comment: Only `System.Web.HttpUtility` exists in NetStd2+ : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web?view=netstandard-2.1 so correct, you can `not` include those ASP classes in a portable lib.